# ¿Cómo poner los dos div juntos teniendo los dos float:right?

Tags: html, css

Quiero poner dos divs juntos pero los dos tienen float:right, uno el padre y otro dentro del hijo de otro elemento y no se como hacer para que se posicionen los dos juntos. Intente ponerle top:0px al segundo_float, pero se sobrepone, no lo pone al lado. El código:

```css
html,body{
height:100%;
width:100%;
position:absolute;
}
.rdiv, .tdiv{
background:yellow;
width:25%;
height:25%;
}
.tdiv{
background:purple;
float:right;
width:10%;
}
.segundo_float{
width:1vh;
height:100%;
background:black;
float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="rdiv">
<div class="segundo_float"></div>
</div>
<div class="tdiv"></div>
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Se puede modificar el HTML y/o el CSS para responder tu pregunta ???obligatoriamente hay que responder usando float ????

Comment: segundo_float debe de estar dentro de rdiv a la derecha, puedo ponerle right:0 y absolute al segundo_float, pero lo que pasa esque se me pone al final de la pantalla, y aunque le modifique el right para que se ponga donde toca, deja de ser responsive. No se si se puede hacer de otra manera usando solo css. El tdiv da igual que no tenga float si esta al lado. El html debe de estar así pero puedes modificar el float. Gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: Aunque preferiría si hay alguna manera de hacerlo que sea con el float.